# Value not updating from axios response in vue

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am not able to update the object temp after the axios call.

Please help.

This is whole code. I have used the component in vue. I am very new to vue and components.

Below is app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;

Vue.component('shipping-address', require('./components/ShippingAddress.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
export default app;
```

```
<div id="app">
    <shipping-address ></shipping-address>
</div>
```

```
<template>
  <div>
    SName: <span>{{temp}}</span>                    
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return{
        temp:'a'
    }
  },
  mounted(){
      this.fetchArticles();
  },
  methods:{
      fetchArticles() {
          this.temp = 'b'
          const vm = this;
            axios.get('user/addresses')
            .then(response=>{this.temp = 'c';})
            .catch( error => console.log(error));
        },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `.then(response => { vm.temp = 'c'  })`; you can't return a variable assignment, put your code between brackets to make the arrow function run a function instead of returning an expression.

Comment: I see some issues here. You should make your `mounted()` function `async` and add `await` before the axios call, apart from the suggestion in the answer.

Comment: Only if you're assigning the response from axios to a variable in the scope of the mounted function. Using `.then()` and `.catch()` and handling the variable assignment within the callback function should work without async/await syntax.

Comment: May bad, didn't think about the promise syntax. Also don't see a need to assign `this` to another const `vm` and use it. If using array function, `this` within the function is attached to the context. And you should use add `debugger;` in the mounted function and see in vue dev tools what's going on.

Comment: I have modified the code. Please check again. I am using the component. Moreover in the Vue tab of the Chrome developer tools i am only seeing component as Root not able to see Shipping Address other component inside the root. Please help

Comment: I think the get request should be ```axios.get('/user/addresses')``` instead of ```axios.get('users/addresses')```.

Comment: If your shipping address component doesn't load, check the console tab of your developer tools to see if Vue raises any errors and post them in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the answer.

By mistake i included app.js two times. One in footer blade file and one in the blade file itself.